# Extract tag with three or more search strings in beautiful soup tree

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search for 3 (or more) specific RegEx inside HTML documents.
The HTML files do all have different forms and layouts but specific words, so I can search for the words.

Now, I'd like to return the line:

```html
<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em>  <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
```

I've tried plenty of versions of the code but I'm stumbling in the dark currently.

```
import re
from bs4 import Tag, BeautifulSoup

text = """
<body>
<div>
<div>
<p>This 19 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another test</p>
<p>19 that is yet <em>another</em> great <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em>  <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
"""


def searchme(bstag):
    print("searchme")
    regex1 = r"17738"
    regex2 = r"CAR"
    regex3 = r"greaterly"

    switch1 = 0
    switch2 = 0
    switch3 = 0

    result1 = bstag.find(string=re.compile(regex1, re.MULTILINE))
    if len(result1) >= 1:
        switch1 = 1
        result2 = result1.parent.find(string=re.compile(regex2, re.MULTILINE))
        if len(result2) >= 1:
            switch2 = 1
            result3 = result2.parent.find_all(string=re.compile(regex3, re.MULTILINE))
            if len(result3) >= 1:
                switch3 = 1

    if switch1 == 1 and switch2 == 1 and switch3 == 1:
        return bstag
    else:
        if bstag.parent is not None:
            searchme(bstag.parent)
        else:
            searchme(result1.parent)

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
el = searchme(soup)
print(el)
```

## EDIT 1

Updated the desired returned code

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html =  """
<body>
<div>
<div>
<p>This 19 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another test</p>
<p>19 that is yet <em>another</em> great <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em>  <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
"""
regex1 = r"17738"
regex2 = r"CAR"
regex3 = r"greaterly"
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
p3s = doc.getElementsByReg(regex3,tag='p')
for p in p3s:
   p2 = p.getNext('p')
   if p2.contains([regex1,regex2],attr='html'):
      # print (p2.outerHtml)
      print (p2.parent.outerHtml) # Get div
      break
```

Result:

```
<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em>  <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting approach. I've updated my question. `greaterly` is in a separate paragraph. So the whole div should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to have understood the example, given that there is no

element in the `text` object which contains all the 3 `regex` terms.

If, however, I have properly parsed the question, I would recommend not to use `regex` for this task (which is sub-optimal in terms of computational time and burden), but rely on a much simpler `in`. Below you can find a MWE, in which I have slightly modified the text in your original example to contain the line you are interested in.

```
from bs4 import Tag, BeautifulSoup

text = """
<body>
<div>
<div>
<p>This 19 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another test</p>
<p>19 that is yet <em>another</em> great <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em> greaterly <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
"""

t1 = '17738' # terms to be searched
t2 = 'CAR'
t3 = 'greaterly'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.findAll('div'): # parse the text line by line
    if t1 in row.text and t2 in row.text and t3 in row.text: # if the line contains all terms
        print(row.text)
```

Comment: Thanks .. that does look more elegant and less confusing. However, I've updated my question. `greaterly` isn't in the same `<p>` paragraph.
So in case I find one or two matches in one sentence, I'd like to search for the 3rd match within the parent element.

Comment: Great, now I got that. I will edit the answer - in a word, you should change the looping from 'p' to 'div' (please note that the HTML source si malformed, hence you have two nested <div>s, with no further distinctions, and the loop will go through the element twice)

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML is malformed? And searching for div here prints 2 results (the full div and the 2nd inner div).

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling: the HTML is not malformed, but the <div> elements don't have further specifications (e.g., classes, types, etc.), hence there is no way to only loop through one <div> at a time, other than customized code which loses generality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `div:has(> p)`, which will search `<div>` tags that have `<p>` tags directly under them.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<body>
<div>
<div>
<p>This 19 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another test</p>
<p>19 that is yet <em>another</em> great <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em>  <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>"""


to_search = ['17738', 'CAR', 'greaterly']
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

results = []
for div in soup.select('div:has(> p)'):  # search only divs that have <p> tags DIRECTLY under them
    if all(word in div.text for word in to_search):
        results.append(div)

print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[<div>
<p>This 17 is A BIG test</p>
<p>This is another greaterly test</p>
<p>17738 that is yet <em>another</em> <strong>test</strong> with a CAR</p>
</div>]
```

Comment: Thank you.
The problem here as well is, I don't know how the structure of the HTML documents will be. It might be divs, might be spans, might be tables.